# Chrome tab focus

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, focus

I know how to move focus between tabs but this is a different question.  If two "instances" of Chrome are open, I need to direct the focus and all subsequent actions to the originally opened instance.  Allow me to clarify (sort of).  Our call center application loads Chrome and its home page upon log in.  The agents have two monitors and often have a web site open on Monitor 2 in addition to our home page on Monitor 1.  My extension checks the open tabs for one with a specific title and if found takes some action.  My issue:  If the agent is on the second monitor when the call hits, the new url pops on screen 2.  I need it to pop on screen 1 and leave screen 2 untouched.  Any thoughts on how I can move the focus from screen 2 back to screen 1 before my extension does anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Your extension checks for open tabs for a tab with a specific title, and takes some action when its found. You can get the ID of that tab based on the title condition and can use the `chrome.tabs.update()` method with the `active` property set to `true`.

You can find further details about this on [Chrome extension's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-updateProperties-active).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chirag64.  I was having difficulty framing my question.  You were able to answer it though

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  It is not quite answered though.  Here's my issue in a bit more detail:  Ours is a call center based company.  Our main agent screen contains our desktop application (Chrome based).  I wrote an extension that checks the open tabs and closes the duplicate tabs then moves the focus to the correct tab.  The problem arises when the agent has another site open on his other monitor (Chrome is the default browser).  If the other Chrome instance is active (focused) and a call arrives, my extension does its job but pops the new screen onto the other instance of Chrome).

Comment: I was thinking about using the Chrome windows api rather than the tabs api to check which parent (instance) of Chrome is active then move the focus to the primary monitor if necessary.  Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: [As per the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-updateProperties-active), it doesn't matter whether the tab you choose to focus is in the same window where your current focus is. So if you focus on the tab which is on the primary monitor, that appropriate window should also get selected.

Comment: Or, you could get the windows focus alternatively using the `chrome.windows.update()` method with the `focused` property set to `true`. You can find its [documentation here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-updateInfo-focused).